# Why is getTimestamp() affected by setTimezone()

Tags: php, datetime, unix-timestamp

I've been struggling quite a while with PHP's DateTime classes. My understanding is that a UNIX-timstamp is always in UTC, regardless of the timezone.

That's why I am quite confused with this code sample.

```
$date1 = new DateTime("@1351382400"); // Sun Oct 28 2012 02:00:00 GMT+2 (DST)
var_dump($date1->getTimestamp()); //prints: 1351382400
$date1->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone("Europe/Stockholm"););
var_dump($date1->getTimestamp()); //prints: 1351386000
```

As you can see setTimezone() changes the result of getTimestamp().

Is it expected that setTimezone() affects getTimestamp()?

Comment: Say hello to a daylight savings transition.

Comment: Sure thing, but is it expected?

Comment: Clearly not by you, and that's what's important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The amount that you're off is 3600 seconds, or 1 hour.

I think that what you're seeing is because the date you picked is the end of Daylight Savings Time in Stockholm.  If you use a different date, you don't get that effect:

```
$now = time();
echo "            now: $now\n";

$date1 = new DateTime("@{$now}");
echo "     date1 here: {$date1->getTimestamp()}\n";
$date1->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone("Europe/Stockholm"));
echo "date1 Stockholm: {$date1->getTimestamp()}\n";
```

Output:

```
            now: 1352321491
     date1 here: 1352321491
date1 Stockholm: 1352321491
```

I'm not sure if this is a bug or not, but it doesn't happen if you don't pick a date on which DST is changing.

Comment: That's true, but does seem a bit inconsistant. I'm dealing with time series throughout the year - and two days per year this is a problem for me. Well, being aware of if makes it possible to work around.

Comment: This seems to be a known issue, according to [this PHP bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=51051)

Comment: Ah, then it is a bug. Thanks for finding out!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, unix timestamp is the current time as per the date object or your current machine time from Epoch.

Comment: Ok, in that case setTimezone() should not affect the unix timestamp returned by getTimestamp()? Is it a bug then?